# Paragraph in to one line? (remove line break)

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

I'm writing a macro to extract some information outta website. 
Full code here : http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/25QI

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:pdpMemberSizes&&ID:sizesList* EXTRACT=TXT

Returns

```
XS



S



M



L



XL
```

I want to know how to remove the line breaks and join them with a comma or something. I have very little knowledge in javascript so it's hard for me to solve this.  I would like know how to save all the extractions in one line and go to next line in the next loop>> repeat.

Comment: substitute ',' on newlines `/\n+/,/`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SET delimiter ","
SET replaced EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\n+/g, '{{delimiter}}');")
```

Comment: Works great. :) Thank you very much.! :)